# javascript private function access public variable

Tags: javascript, class, private, public

i have this class:

```
function ctest() {
    this.var1 = "haha";
    this.func1 = function() {
        alert(this.var1);
        func2();
        alert(this.var1);
    }
    var func2 = function() {
        this.var1 = "huhu";
    }
}
```

and call it :

```
    var myobj = new ctest();
    myobj.func1();
```

isn't supposed that the second alert will popup "huhu" ? func2 is private, can it not access the var1 public variable ?

if a private function cannot access a public variable, how can i do it ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, there is not such thing like `private` here.

Comment: This `obj.func1()` should presumably be `myobj.func1()`

Comment: @forsvarir yeah it should - I fixed it for him.

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this to learn how `this` works.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to provide a context for the call to `func2`:

```
this.func1 = function() {
    alert(this.var1);
    func2.call(this);
    alert(this.var1);
}
```

Without the context the call will use the global object (i.e. `window`) - you should see when you run your current code that `window.var1` is getting created between the two alerts.

Comment: if i do what you suggested it says that func2() is not a function

Comment: @MIrrorMirror ah, umm, yes - hold on!

Comment: That won't work: func2 is a private variable, not a property.

Comment: @xdazz fixed now - you have to use `.call` to add a context to a locally scoped function.

Comment: works now, but it seems highly unintuitive, would have never figured it out! thought that my original version would be sufficient. Thanks!

Comment: yeah, actually the (deleted) answer from @dystroy is OK too - I completely failed to spot first time around that `func2` is only locally scoped and not part of `this`.

Comment: if i understand it correctly I actually pass the owner as a parameter, right?

Comment: @MIrrorMirror no, the first parameter to `.call` sets the implicit `this` value within the function.

Comment: function ctest() {
 this.iteration = 0;
 this.func1 = function() {
  var result = func2.call(this, "haha");
  alert(result);
 }
 var func2 = function(test) {
  this.iteration++;
  test = test + "lol";
  if ( this.iteration < 5 ) {
   func2.call(this, test);
  } else {
   return test;
  }
 }
}

isn't result supposed to be "hahalollollollol" ? i get an undefined here

posted here because i didn't want to open a new question

Comment: @MIrrorMirror: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this to learn how `this` works. Once you understood it, it's not unintuitive anymore ;)

Answer (score 12):

Functions are not tied to instances, therefore your invocation of `func2` ends up as invocation without `this` pointing to the expected instance.

You can either fix the invocation to include the context:

```
function ctest() {
    this.var1 = "haha";
    this.func1 = function() {
        alert(this.var1);
        func2.call(this);
        alert(this.var1);
    }
    var func2 = function() {
        this.var1 = "huhu";
    }
}
```

Or you can keep a variable with the wanted object reference around:

```
function ctest() {
    var that = this;
    this.var1 = "haha";
    this.func1 = function() {
        alert(this.var1);
        func2();
        alert(this.var1);
    }
    var func2 = function() {
        that.var1 = "huhu";
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide further reading on this topic, as i want to know which is best practise and why

Comment: @InsOp I suggest reading the MDN help on the "this" keyword: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
function ctest() {
    this.var1 = "haha";
    this.func1 = function() {
        alert(this.var1);
        func2();
        alert(this.var1);
    }
    var func2 = function() {
        this.var1 = "huhu";
    }.bind(this);
}
```

Note that the browser support for this is not perfect.

Comment: Why use `that` _and_ `.bind()` at the same time?

Comment: @Alnitak: Poor copy and pasting

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as private in JS, but you can play with scopes using the [closures](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/).

Let's say for instance that in your example you don't need to expose `var1` as public property. You could easily rewrite your code as the follows:

```
function ctest() {
    var var1 = "haha";

    this.func1 = function() {
        alert(var1);
        func2();
        alert(var1);
    }

    var func2 = function() {
        var1 = "huhu";
    }
}
```

Because both `func1` and `func2` shares the same scope – they are defined in the same function, `ctest` – they can access to the same variables. Of course in that case you don't have `var1` exposed, so: `myobj.var1` will be `undefined`.

If you want `var1` to be exposed as property, then what you need is [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) `func2` to the object instance you created in the constructor:

```
function ctest() {
    this.var1 = "haha";
    this.func1 = function() {
        alert(this.var1);
        func2();
        alert(this.var1);
    }
    var func2 = function() {
        this.var1 = "huhu";
    }.bind(this);
}
```

Otherwise `func2` will have a different context object (`this`). If the browser doesn't support `bind` and you don't want use a shim (as shown in the link above), you can take advantage of the closures again:

```
function ctest() {
    this.var1 = "haha";
    this.func1 = function() {
        alert(this.var1);
        func2();
        alert(this.var1);
    }
    var context = this;
    var func2 = function() {
        context.var1 = "huhu";
    }
}
```

IMVHO is less elegant.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ctest() {
    this.var1 = "haha";
    this.func1 = function() {
        alert(this.var1);
        func2(this);
        alert(this.var1);
    }
    var func2 = function(obj) {
        obj.var1 = "huhu";
    }
}
```

And there is other way to solve this problem, check the other answers :)

Comment: @Alnitak But that will not be a problem, `obj` is parameter.